# How do I get larger fleets?

Tags: endless-space

How do you extend the amount of ships in a fleet? I am sowers and can only have 5 but the humans have like 15 or something.

Answer (score 4):

The maximum number of ships per fleet depend on the number of command point used by each ship. Small ship require less points than larger ones. So, you can have more if you only use the smallest.

You can increase the number of command points with the faction trait ''big fleet'' and you also increase the cap of command point with some technologies

http://endlessspace.wikia.com/wiki/Command_Points